# Async await not catching 401 axios with onupload progress callback

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-status-code-401

I added a progress bar to my form saving by adding a callback to the axios service. Even though I am getting a 401, it runs the next line in the try block and not the catch block. Here is my code:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
function (response) {
    return response;
},
function (error) {
    if (401 === error.response.status) {
        console.log('unauthorized')
        return Promise.reject(error);
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}
);
export const addCourse = (data, { onUploadProgress }) =>{ 
axios.post(`/clients/${data.clientId}/courses`, data, {
    onUploadProgress : (progressEvent) => {
        const progress = parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total));
        onUploadProgress(progress);
      }
}).then(patchData)
};
```

Then in the Component to save the form I have this:

```
const handleSubmit = async ({ title, description, setSubmitting }) => {

        const clientId = user.client_id
        const name = title

    try {
        const course = await addCourse({ name, description, clientId},{ onUploadProgress: setProgress});
        toast.add('Course Saved', theme.colors.green)
        setSubmitting(false);
    } catch (error) {
        toast.add(error.response.data.error, theme.colors.red)
        setSubmitting(false)
    }
};
```

It always adds a success toast and doesnt throw the error. My login has a regular axios call without the onupload progress and catches the 401. Not sure if I formatted my callback wrong. Any help would be great, thanks!